# Moving AutoParallaxBackground's ParallaxEntity in X and Y direction

Tags: andengine

Currently I can move AutoParallaxBackground's "ParallaxEntity" in **one axis**. Like:

```
final AutoParallaxBackground autoParallaxBackground = new AutoParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0, 12);
autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0.0f, new Sprite(0, 0, resourcesManager.gameBackgroundRegion, vbom)));
autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-3.0f, new Sprite(0, 300, resourcesManager.gameCloudFarRegion, vbom)));
```

This will make the "gameCloudFarRegion" move left to right.

I want to move something from **Top to bottom or bottom to top**, I mean **Y axis**.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user on the forums has [implemented a custom class](http://www.andengine.org/forums/features/parallax-x-y-scrolling-class-t808.html) for doing this. From their post:

> Should be quite flexible, you can tile in just x (as the current
>   parallax background, for side scrollers etc), just y (to make a top
>   down shooter etc), or x & y (repeating starfields for free shooters
>   etc).You can also place individual non repeating items in the
>   background parallax, e.g a distant planet, the castle off in the hills
>   etc.